# C++: Expression: string subscript out of range

Tags: c++

I facing an issue with a bug in C++. Here is  the code:

Error as:  Expression: string subscript out of range

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

void removeAllchars1(std::string s)
{
  int len = strlen(s.c_str());
  std::string b;
  int len2 = strlen(b.c_str());
  for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
  {
    if(isdigit(*(s.c_str()+i)))
    {
      b[len2]=s[i];
      ++len2;
    }
  }
  std::cout <<"\nAfter removeAllchars1 function is:"<< *(b.c_str());
}
```

Comment: Hm... are you going to show us some code, too? Also, posts containing "asap" instead of a question tend to get downvoted and closed.

Comment: `b[len2]` always accesses past the end of the string. Also, just use `s.size()`.

Comment: Hello, Tomek.
void removeAllchars1(std::string s)
{
 int len = strlen(s.c_str());
 std::string b;
 int len2 = strlen(b.c_str());
 for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
 {
  if(isdigit(*(s.c_str()+i)))
  {
   b += s[i];
  }
 }
 std::cout <<"\nAfter removeAllchars1 function is:"<< *(b.c_str());
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
 char *str = "hoc_r123";
 removeAllchars1(str);
 return 0;
}

Answer (score 2):

```
b[len2]=s[i];
```

Since `len2` is the length of `b` (albeit computed in a rather convoluted manner - what's wrong with `b.length()`?), this is out of range, as the error says. If you want to append the character to the string, then do that:

```
b += s[i];
```

Comment: Hi Mike Seymour

b +=s[i]; // Right about syntax c++ on build. but, it is not right about logic. 
Exampple: 
 char *str = "hoc_r123";
 removeAllchars1(str); // The reult is 1

Comment: @NgocPhan: That's because you're printing `*(b.c_str())`, which is just the first character. Try printing `b` instead. More generally, stop calling `c_str()` except when you actually need a C-compatible string (which you don't need anywhere in this function).